# How to load lots of images smoothly in a CollectionView?

Tags: xamarin

I have about 600 images to display in a CollectionView( from URLs).
I have created the following CollectionView :

```xml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Models}">
 <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <ff:CachedImage Source="{Binding image}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
 </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Right now, there is a lot of lag. How can I avert this?

Comment: Maybe you need to [load-data-incrementally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data#load-data-incrementally)

Comment: use incremental loading, or pre-load the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Replaced CollectionView with a ListView and set its CachingStrategy to "RecycleElementAndDataTemplate".